# Custom DataGridColumn Binding value

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datagridviewcolumn

I am trying to create a custom DataGridColumn that simply shows a tick or cross icon depending on the Binding value, but the Binding value is always false

```
public class DataGridBoolColumn : DataGridBoundColumn
{
    private const double DATAGRIDBOOLCOLUMN_leftMargin = 12.0;
    private const double DATAGRIDBOOLCOLUMN_rightMargin = 12.0;

    public bool Value
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(ValueProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ValueProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Value.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Value", typeof(bool), typeof(DataGridBoolColumn), new PropertyMetadata(false));

    private FrameworkElement CreateIcon()
    {
        // Set Binding to ValueProperty
        BindingOperations.SetBinding(this, ValueProperty, Binding);

        PackIconMaterial icon = new PackIconMaterial();
        icon.Margin = new Thickness(DATAGRIDBOOLCOLUMN_leftMargin, 0.0, DATAGRIDBOOLCOLUMN_rightMargin, 0.0);
        icon.Height = 14.0;            

        // Determine if the icon should show Check or Cross based on Value
        if (Value)
        {
            icon.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(new Color() { A = 255, R = 22, G = 100, B = 44 });
            icon.Kind = PackIconMaterialKind.Check;
        }
        else
        {
            icon.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(new Color() { A = 255, R = 128, G = 16, B = 42 });
            icon.Kind = PackIconMaterialKind.Close;
        }

        return icon;
    }

    protected override FrameworkElement GenerateEditingElement(DataGridCell cell, object dataItem)
    {
        return CreateIcon();
    }

    protected override FrameworkElement GenerateElement(DataGridCell cell, object dataItem)
    {
        return CreateIcon();
    }

}
```

Then in the XAML I bind the value

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=FilteredItems}">
    <local:DataGridBoolColumn Header="Trackable" Binding="{Binding Path=IsTrackable}" />
</DataGrid>
```

The Cross icon shows in the column, but the Value always returns False, which is not correct. It is not taking the Binding value.

There are no XAML binding errors.

How do I redirect the Binding to a custom dependency property?

Comment: If your dependecy property is named `Value`, then when you use your `UserControl` should look like this: `<local:DataGridBoolColumn Header="Trackable" Value="{Binding Path=IsTrackable}" />`

Comment: I get a XAML Binding  error when I do that... No DataContext found for Binding (in code) and Cannot find governing FrameworkElement or FrameworkContentElement for target element   (at Runtime)

Comment: whats this for?
BindingOperations.SetBinding(this, ValueProperty, Binding);
I think that should be removed, and then use the code as above:
<local:DataGridBoolColumn Header="Trackable" Value="{Binding Path=IsTrackable}" />

Comment: I couldn't get this to work at all... GenerateElement was not being called with the correct dataObject... I just trashed the idea and duplicated the code, instead of trying to be clever and reusing it

Comment: @craig1231: Does that mean that your issue has been solved?